# FactoryGirl creating objects in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, factory-bot

When I boot up my rails console in development I see FactoryGirl creating objects.  Clearly I'm doing it wrong, but what's the right way to do this?  This code makes my tests work...

```
# tests/factories/board.rb
FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :word do
        sequence(:text) { |n| "FAKETEXT#{n}" }
    end

    factory :board do
        trait :has_words do
            words [
                FactoryGirl.create(:word, id: "514b81cae14cfa78f335e250"),
                FactoryGirl.create(:word, id: "514b81cae14cfa7917e443f0"),
                FactoryGirl.create(:word, id: "514b81cae14cfa79182407a2"),
                FactoryGirl.create(:word, id: "514b81cae14cfa78f581c534")
            ]
        end
    end

end
```

Note there's no mention of factory anything in any file in my `config` directory, so whatever loading is happening automatically by the gem.  The relevant part of my `Gemfile` reads:

```
# Stuff not to use in production
group :development, :test do
    # Command-line debugger for development
    gem "debugger"

    # for unit testing - replace fixtures
    gem "factory_girl_rails"
end
```

So I could just take factory girl out of the development environment.  But I think the fact that these records are being created before the factory is being used is a sign that I've written my factory incorrectly.  But if you tell me the factory is written correctly, I'll just do that.

Comment: is this code in spec/factories?

Comment: That code is in a factory file.  Comment added with location.

Comment: How is factory_girl listed in your gem file?

Comment: Updated with relevant part of Gemfile.

Comment: Doesn't look like the factory is incorrect.  Looks like there must be something calling it outside of your tests.  How about doing a global text search of your app for `FactoryGirl` and see if it's called anywhere?

Comment: @muttonlamb the word "factory" never appears outside the test/ directory.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem. There are 2 ways to fix this,

### 1. Use FactoryGirl syntax to reference Factory within a Factory.

Replace `FacotryGirl.create(:my_factory)` with `factory: :my_factory`

More info on this, https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

### 2. `factory_girl :require => false` in Gemfile

This causes Factories to generate objects on boot,

```
group :development, :test do  
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

**Why?** During Rails boot, Bundler requires all the gems in the `development` group, and it seems that FactoryGirl requires all their factory files. Requiring the factories evaluates the Ruby code, and thus, `FactoryGirl.create(:my_factory)` gets called.

This can be fixed by,

```
# Gemfile
group :development, :test do  
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false
end
```

**Just make sure to manually require factory_girl in your test environment**, EG

```
# spec_helper
require 'factory_girl'
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move factory girl out of the development environment.

I had the same issue, so I just did

```
group :test do
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

And works like a charm.

I'm not using those gems at all in development so its correct to just define them in test.

Answer (score 0):

for each factories or model, you have to put in different file

```
spec/factories/word_factory.rb
spec/factories/board_factory.rb
```

So the content of each factory, you can do something similar to this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :board do
    word
    special_id
  end
end
```

when in your test folder such as models/board_spec.rb

you can create your object

```
let(:word) { FactoryGirl.create(:word)
let(:board) { FactoryGirl.create(:board, word: word) }
```

nt sure is this what you need,correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Moving the factory definitions to their own files didn't change anything.  And I'm using test_unit not rspec so I'm not sure what to make of the rest of your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the words created when the factory is invoked and not at Rails startup, then you need to place the array of words inside a block, to wit:

```
trait :has_words do
        words do [
            FactoryGirl.create(:word, id: "514b81cae14cfa78f335e250"),
            FactoryGirl.create(:word, id: "514b81cae14cfa7917e443f0"),
            FactoryGirl.create(:word, id: "514b81cae14cfa79182407a2"),
            FactoryGirl.create(:word, id: "514b81cae14cfa78f581c534")
            ]
        end 
    end
```